# Nightly build in node js

Tags: node.js, testing, automation

I need some suggestion about tools and module regrading node js. I want to set up nightly build system on my server (My local machine).  My motive is testing REST APIs and socket APIs. I am searching tools for it especially **socket testing**.

I need some extra stuff like code coverage,  testing report etc. Is it any tool available in node-js like `jenkins + their plugin`, `JUnit/PHPUnit`, `phing/puppet`  and especially should be open source.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score -1):

for sockets in node js use [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/)

and supertest for automating requests and asserting response

mocha for code coverage